# Trouble with URL encoding <-> utf8 <-> iso

Tags: java, encoding, utf-8, character-encoding, iso-8859-1

I have a strange issue involving a web call that I'm unable to actually replicate locally.

I'm testing a web service that must be set up to receive UTF-8 characters. So far, testing I've done is not proving fruitful. Here's a sample of what I sent as a parameter:

`Nestlé and Mötley Crüe`

But here's what I receive as a parameter:

`NestlÃ© and MÃ¶tley CrÃ¼e`

Note that this is exactly what I get when I call `request.getParameter()`. I've already done the necessary steps to ensure everything is being encoded as UTF-8 before it even gets to my servlet (through Tomcat 7). All of my research is telling me that this is a routine encoding issue when going from UTF-8 to ISO-8859-1. Trouble is, ISO-8859-1 is not present in any aspect of this system (system's default file encoding is UTF-8, the POST's body encoding is UTF-8).

So I figured I'd fiddle a bit with it in a local environment and try to come up with a solution. What follows is a dump of the output with some description of what's going on.

```
normal: Nestlé and Mötley Crüe
encoded (utf): Nestl%C3%A9+and+M%C3%B6tley+Cr%C3%BCe
encoded (iso): Nestl%E9+and+M%F6tley+Cr%FCe
normal utf bytes: [4E, 65, 73, 74, 6C, C3, A9, 20, 61, 6E, 64, 20, 4D, C3, B6, 74, 6C, 65, 79, 20, 43, 72, C3, BC, 65]
normal iso bytes: [4E, 65, 73, 74, 6C, E9, 20, 61, 6E, 64, 20, 4D, F6, 74, 6C, 65, 79, 20, 43, 72, FC, 65]
utf bytes to utf string: Nestlé and Mötley Crüe
utf bytes to iso string: NestlÃ© and MÃ¶tley CrÃ¼e
iso bytes to utf string: Nestl? and M?tley Cr?
iso bytes to iso string: Nestlé and Mötley Crüe
```

The first line is what I sent in, and what I expect to receive.

The next two are the results of using `URLEncoder.encode` with UTF-8 and ISO-8859-1, respectively.

The two after that are hex codes for each byte of the string in the first line. Obviously, é in UTF-8 is represented in two bytes (C3, A9) while a single byte (E9) in ISO.

The next 4 lines are some tests I did making new Strings with different encodings (literally, `new String(byteArr, charset)`.

So this is all fine, and expected behavior, albeit locally. Plus, I notice that the UTF -> ISO line is exactly what I'm seeing, so I fiddle with the servlet code to treat it as ISO, since UTF hasn't been working. When I set up the servlet code to do this, here's my results:

```
description: NestlÃ© and MÃ¶tley CrÃ¼e
url iso enc: Nestl%E9+and+M%F6tley+Cr%FCe
url iso dec: NestlÃ© and MÃ¶tley CrÃ¼e
bytes (UTF): [4E, 65, 73, 74, 6C, C3, A9, 20, 61, 6E, 64, 20, 4D, C3, B6, 74, 6C, 65, 79, 20, 43, 72, C3, BC, 65]
bytes (ISO): [4E, 65, 73, 74, 6C, E9, 20, 61, 6E, 64, 20, 4D, F6, 74, 6C, 65, 79, 20, 43, 72, FC, 65]
utf bytes to utf string: NestlÃ© and MÃ¶tley CrÃ¼e
utf bytes to iso string: NestlÃÂ© and MÃÂ¶tley CrÃÂ¼e
iso bytes to utf string: Nestlï¿½ and Mï¿½tley Crï¿½
iso bytes to iso string: NestlÃ© and MÃ¶tley CrÃ¼e
```

So many differences! In this output, the second and third line is where I attempt to URL encode the value in ISO, and then decode it in ISO.

What baffles my brain right now is how in the world the system figures that byte `E9` in ISO-8859-1 somehow results in `Ã©`. That, and what the heck is going on in the conversion methods of the servlet code, and why are they radically different from the local example?

`E9` in ISO is `é`

`C3` in ISO is `Ã`

`A9` in ISO is `©`

`E9` in UTF gives me either `ï¿½` or just `?` according to those byte->string methods.

`C3 A9` in UTF is `é`

Any assistance or insight would be great.